Getting amsalpha to work with accented names
I'm having trouble trying to do three things at once:

Use the amsalpha style in bibtex.
Make my reference to Euler's 1735 paper cited as [Eul1735] not [Eul35].
Use a reference with an Author with an accent in the first three letters of their name.

Originally, to get 1 and 2 to work, I used the solution in this answer:
19th century references in bibtex with amsalpha
It worked very well, although I do not understand it. However, whatever it does is not compatible with trying to do 3. So a solution to this problem might just be a variant 2. Both 2 and 3 work individually. Here is an example where there is an issue.
#######
 \documentclass[reqno,table]{amsart}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backref=page,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}


 \ifdefined\NewCommandCopy
  \NewCommandCopy\latexbibitem\bibitem
\else
  \let\latexbibitem\bibitem
  \usepackage{xparse}
\fi
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \RenewDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{O{}m}
  {
   \nineteen_bibitem:en { \nineteen_bibitem_check:n { #1 } } { #2 }
  }

 \cs_new_protected:Nn \nineteen_bibitem:nn { \latexbibitem[#1]{#2} }
 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \nineteen_bibitem:nn { e }
 \cs_new:Nn \nineteen_bibitem_check:n
  {
   \str_case:nnF { #1 }
    {
     {Eul35}{Eul1735}
    }
    { #1 }
  }
 \ExplSyntaxOff
 


\begin{document}

The proof~\cite{Lex}, which uses the argument of~\cite{Euler}.


\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{Accents}



\end{document}

############


@preamble{"\renewcommand{\MR}[1]{}"}.


@misc {Lex,
    AUTHOR = {L{\'e}x},
     TITLE = {I did it!},
}


@misc {Euler,
    AUTHOR = {Euler, Leonhard},
     TITLE = {De summis serierum reciprocarum},
     YEAR = {1735},
     }




The code for the expl3 version has been updated

LaTeX3 code is often difficult to understand with all the argument types and command variants etc. Here a simplified LaTeX2e version. Side effect is that it also works for the MWE.
\documentclass[reqno,table]{amsart}
\usepackage[backref=page,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\ifdefined\NewCommandCopy
  \NewCommandCopy\latexbibitem\bibitem
\else
  \let\latexbibitem\bibitem
  \usepackage{xparse}
\fi

\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{%
\def\mykey{#1}%
\def\cmpkey{Eul35}%
\ifx\mykey\cmpkey%
\latexbibitem[Eul1735]{#2}%
\else%
\latexbibitem[#1]{#2}%
\fi%
}

\begin{document}

The proof~\cite{Lex}, which uses the argument of~\cite{Euler}.

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{amsaccents}

\end{document}

Result:


I have failed so far, however, to adjust this for multiple pre 19th century names, working on it.

@user297024 that would be something like \def\cmpkeyb{Xyz12}\def\cmpkeyc{Zyx34} etc and then \ifx\mykey\cmpkey\latexbibitem[Eul1735]{#2}\else\ifx\mykey\cmpkeyb\latexbibitem[Xyz1812]{#2}\else\ifx\mykey\cmpkeyc\latexbibitem[Zyx1834]{#2}\else\latexbibitem[#1]{#2}\fi\fi\fi\fi. Of course this gets rather unwieldy when adding a lot of cases, more readable approaches are possible for example by looping through a list for each century.

Thanks, ChatGPT was able to help me the rest of the way, so the automation process (for the 15 papers) was quite easy in the end.
